# data: $(this).serialize() Not Working in Wizard Form

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

data: `$(this).serialize()` does not post to php. From the done(function(data) I can view the serialize() on screen using

```
$("div").text($("form").serialize());
```

but it does not post to url: 'submission.php'

I am a newbie. Please help.

My wizard-form has all its names="" correctly. I've spent 2 days now trying to adjust the  to get working.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.wizard-card').bootstrapWizard({onTabShow: function(tab, navigation, index) {
            var $total = navigation.find('li').length;
            var $current = index+1;
            var $percent = ($current/$total) * 100;
            $('.wizard-card').find('.bar').css({width:$percent+'%'});
        }});
        $('.wizard-card .finish').click(function() {
            // show that something is loading
            $('#response').html("Loading...");

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'submission.php',
                data: $(this).serialize()

            })

                    .done(function(data){
                        $(location).attr('href', 'submission.php')

                    })

                    .fail(function() {
                        // just in case posting your form failed
                        $('#response').html("Oops. Try again.")

                    });

            // to prevent refreshing the whole page page
            return false;

        });
    });
</script>
```

Its suppose to post the data to submission.php, but it does not post

Comment: `$(this)` is likely not `$("form")` in that context

Comment: There is only one form - I've also tried using the form id and name tags - (not sure if that would even work). Is there something in the <script> that's throwing off the $_POST from registering?

Comment: You need to do a little more debugging.  View the request in your browser's network inspector.  Do you see the parameters being sent as expected?  If not, what do you see?  If you do, then the problem's probably on your PHP side and you should show us that code.

Comment: Also, what exactly are you attempting to achieve by doing `$(location).attr('href', 'submission.php')`?

Comment: @Patrick Q Thanks I am review the Chrome Dev Tools and in the Console Sources I do not see any errors or any variables when I inpsect using Mouse> Click option. The submission.php is simply just echo $_POST['email'] (it will update database, and redirect user to another page).

Comment: Please read my comment more carefully.  You need to view the request (and response) in the Network tab.

Comment: @Patrick Q Thanks - There is no $_POST data there. Please here is the website, would you be so kind... inspect and share + thanks in advance: http://www.ckia.ca/profile-wizard/?popt=1&session=l73018b415o4bph6nhu9ounq01&srtpw=1

Answer (score 0):

> I can view the serialize() on screen using $("div").text($("form").serialize());

Because you're using `$("form").serialize()`, which specifically targets the form element.  What are you targeting with `$(this).serialize()`?  What is `this` in that context?  Since you're in the context of a `$('.wizard-card .finish').click()` handler, `this` is the `.wizard-card .finish` element.  *Not* the form.

Since you've already determined that `$("form").serialize()` works, use it:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'submission.php',
    data: $('form').serialize()
})
```

Note of course that if there's ever more than one `form` on the page then this could have unexpected results.  In that case you'd want to more specifically target it, perhaps using an `id`.

Comment: sorry, I tried $("form").serialize() but it does not work when I replace data: $(this).serialize().

Comment: @PaulHolness: How specifically does it fail?  When you debug, what is the output of `$('form').serialize()`?  What data is being sent to the server?

Comment: When I use $('form').serialize() I use it like this:  .done(function(data){
             
            // show the response
            $("div").text($("form").serialize()); //display on screen
        })

Comment: Note: When I use $(location).attr('href', 'submission.php') I use it like this: .done(function(data){ // show the response $(location).attr('href', 'http://www.ckia.ca/submission.php') })  >>This does not work

Comment: @PaulHolness: This isn't really telling us anything.  You keep throwing around terms like "doesn't work", which specifies nothing about the problem.  If you're not familiar with the debugging tools in your browser, now would be a good time to start using those.  You need to more specifically determine what is failing and how it's failing.  "Doesn't work" could just as easily mean that it works exactly as designed but you have a false assumption somewhere.  We need a more complete example of the problem and a specific description of how it's failing.

Comment: Note2: When I use $('#response').html(data);  I use it like this: .done(function(data){ // show the response $('#response').html(data);  }) >>This does not work - either

Comment: Thank you brb - I will go and check now

Comment: I checked the console listeners (Mouse>click), and Network Response. I just don't see the $_POST. Here is the webpage. Can you help see what I don't see? http://www.ckia.ca/profile-wizard/?popt=1&session=l73018b415o4bph6nhu9ounq01&srtpw=1